# When to use ArrayCollection or Array in as3?

Tags: arrays, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, arraycollection

I know that an `ArrayCollection` is a wrapper over an `Array`, but what I wanted to know is when to choose one over the other? Will the over usage of `ArrayCollection`s result in performance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main advantage of `ArrayCollection` is `collectionChange` event which allows to get advantage of data binding with it.

Some others are:

- Possibility to filter or sort elements of collection without modifying or copying of underlying array.
- Implementation of `ICollectionView` which allows to create a cursor and iterate collection with it.
- Display of multiple arrays in a datagrid / etc (in this case, arrays are automatically converted to arrayCollections anyway)

If you don't need any of these advantages use simple `Array`.

Comment: It should also be noted that ArrayList is a more simplistic ArrayCollection and is slightly faster.  It should also be mentioned that [performance](http://www.jamesward.com/demos/ArrayCollectionPerformance/ArrayCollectionPerformance.html) is an issue with Collections.

Comment: You're right @J_A_X! It hasn't latter two advantages I listed but it can be very useful!

Comment: For the third point, does that include single multi-dimensional arrays?